# My SQL can only return one record but rails is treating it as a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a `type_id`. In the SQLite database, `type_id` is a unique index. If I do a select with `type_id` in the where clause, it follows that the result from the SQL can only contain one record. Rails doesn't see it that way. It treats the result as an AR collection. I can do this,

```
logger.debug 'model[0].type_id = ' + model[0].type_id.to_s
```

but not this

```
logger.debug 'model.type_id = ' + model.type_id.to_s
```

I can do `.first` on the SQL and then I get a single record. I don't like doing it this way because it looks like I'm just taking the the first record in a multi-record set and that's not true. I was hoping Rail could work this out. Is there a better way than using `.first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find_by` finders to get a single instance, e.g.

```
MyModel.find_by_type_id(42).type_id
=> 42
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't been programming for long in Rails. I didn't even know the finders existed. I've been using `.where` to make an SQL. Finders are a so much better.